# ¿Cómo hacer Templates en PHP? plantillas para cadenas (strings)

Tags: php, string, template

¿Cómo se pueden hacer `templates` en una cadena con PHP cómo se hacen en Javascript? me refiero a lo siguiente

```js
var pez = {
  color: "azul",
  tamaño: {
    largo: "20cm",
    ancho: "3cm"
  },
  origen: "México"
}

document.getElementById("pez").innerHTML = `

  El pez ${pez.color} mide ${pez.tamaño.largo} de largo y ${pez.tamaño.ancho} de  ancho <br>
  Vive en ${pez.origen}

`;
```

```html
<div id="pez"></div>
```

Lo que actualmente hago para hacer algo similar es así

```
$dia = "10";
$mes = "Septiembre";
$año = "1999";

echo "Hoy es ".$dia."  del mes ".$mes." del año ".$año;
```

No creo que sea la mejor forma de hacerlo y además se vuelve más enredado en consultas sql 
¿Cómo puedo optimizar este tipo de tareas?

Comment: O sea que quieres poner directamente la variable en el string sin concatenar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

En PHP hay cuatro formas de colocar un string con `'Comillas simples'`, `"Comillas dobles"`, `heredoc` y `nowdoc`:

**[Comillas simples:](http://php.net/manual/es/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single)** Muestra el string tal y como está escrito:

```
<?php 
$nombre = 'mundo';
echo 'Hola $nombre'; //Salida: Hola $nombre
?>
```

---

**[Comillas dobles:](http://php.net/manual/es/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double)** Basicamente permite interpretar `secuencia de escape` y variables:

```
<?php 
$nombre = 'mundo';
echo "Hola {$nombre}"; //Salida: Hola mundo
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes lograrlo, imprimiendo dentro de la cadena de texto las variables gracias a la sintáxis de: `{$variable}`

Te dejo un ejemplo muy similar a lo que haces en JavaScript

```
<?php

$color = "azul";
$tamanio = "grande";
$origen = "México";

echo "El pez es de color: {$color} y tiene un gran tamaño de: {$tamanio}

además es del país {$origen}";
```

Answer (score 0):

creo que te refieres a esto:

```
<?php $perro = (object)["nombre"=>"firulais", "color"=>"cafe", "edad"=>"3"];
echo "mi perro se llama ${perro->nombre}, es de color ${perro->color} y tiene ${perro->edad} años";
//mi perro se llama firulais, es de color cafe y tiene 3 años
```